# uniq does not clean out duplicate entries

Tags: osx-yosemite, uniq

I have a file with a number on each line. I am trying to find out the distinct set of numbers. Below is an excerpt:

```
 550
 400
 4000
 400
 1900
 550
 5000
 400
 1500
 1900
 5000
 4000
 5000
 1900
 5000
```

Passing this through `uniq`, however, doesn't clean out all the duplicates. The number of lines is reduced to `256` from `699`, but there are still multiple lines with `400` or `550`, etc.

I generated this file with a python script, so I know for a fact that on each line there is a blank followed by a number, and followed by `\n`. At least that's what I am printing within the code.

I do not understand what is wrong with the file. Why is `uniq` not working as I thought it would?

(OS X Yosemite, python `2.7`)

Comment: @YOU `uniq` only removes consecutive duplicates, data needs to be sorted before being passed through `uniq`. `cat filename | sort | uniq` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `sort` your contents before calling `uniq`, or you could just use `sort -u`.

From the `uniq` man page:

> uniq - report or omit repeated lines

Note how it says **repeated** and not **duplicate**.

Comment: So then does `uniq` just get rid of consecutive duplicates?